# UpdateTabs Fail (DocuSign C#)

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I don't know why but the UpdateTabs function is not working.

My program :

```
EnvelopesApi envelopeApi = new EnvelopesApi(ApiClient.Configuration);
var temp = envelopeApi.ListTabs(AccountID, idEnveloppe, "1");
SignHere signHere4 = new SignHere
{
    DocumentId = "1",
    PageNumber = "1",
    XPosition = "200",
    YPosition = "200",
    Name= "signaturetest",
    Optional="false",
vScaleValue ="5"
};
temp.SignHereTabs.Add(signHere4);
envelopeApi.UpdateTabs(AccountID, idEnveloppe, "1", temp);
```

The status of the envelope is "created" at this time but I don't see why that would make an error...

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

The method you are using (`UpdateTabs`) can only be used to update *existing* tabs.

You want (it seems) to add a new tab, so you have to use instead

```
envelopesApi.CreateTabs()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add new tabs, you have to use the CreateTabs(). not UpdateTabs() cause this will update the existing tabs.